# Is $ z = 10 $ a removable singularity of $ f(z) = 1 + 2(z - 10) + 3(z - 10)^2 $?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, singularity

From [Complex Variables with Applications (Orloff)](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Complex_Variables_with_Applications_(Orloff)/08%3A_Taylor_and_Laurent_Series/8.09%3A_Poles):

> Poles refer to isolated singularities. So, we suppose $ f(z) $ is analytic on $ 0 < |z - z_0| < r $ has Laurent series
> $$ f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{(z - z_0)^n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z - z_0)^n. $$

Then it defines:

> If all the $ b_n $ are $ 0$, then $ z_0$ is called a removable singularity. That is, if we define $f(z_0) = a_0$ then $f$ is analytic on the disk $|z - z_0|< r $.

I am unable to understand this definition of removable singularity. See this $ f(z) $ for example:

$$
f(z) = 1 + 2(z - 10) + 3(z - 10)^2
$$

All coefficients $ b_n $ are $ 0 $ in the above function. By the definition above, we should call $ 10 $ to be a removable singularity. But why is $ 10 $ a singularity? The function $ f(10) = 1 $ which is a finite value. The function $ f(z) $ appears to be analytic at $ z = 10 $. Then why should we call $ z = 10 $ a removable singularity here.

Is the quoted definition of "removable singularity" correct? Am I misunderstanding the definition?

Comment: The question is meaningless unless you tell us what is the domain of $f$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos From the [source link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Complex_Variables_with_Applications_(Orloff)/08%3A_Taylor_and_Laurent_Series/8.09%3A_Poles), it looks like the domain is the set of complex numbers.

Comment: Then $10$ belongs to the domain, and therefore it is not a singularity. But if the domain is $\Bbb C\setminus\{10\}$, then $10$ is a removable singularity.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks! That is the detail I was missing. Reading the [source link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Complex_Variables_with_Applications_(Orloff)/08%3A_Taylor_and_Laurent_Series/8.09%3A_Poles) again now I see that the domain is supposed to be $ \mathbb{C} \setminus {10} $. That is because the the definition of $ f(z) $ itself supposes that it is analytic on $ 0 < | z - z_0 | $, so it is not assumed to be analytic at $ z = z_0 $. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The quote is talking about functions that are analytic on the punctured disk $0<|z-z_0|<r$. If we take any function $g(z)$ that's actually analytic on the whole disk $|z-z_0|<r$, and then restrict the domain of $g(z)$ to $0<|z-z_0|<r$ to consider it as a function on the punctured disk, then it will always have a removable singularity (which makes sense because we created the "singularity" for no reason!). Your polynomial, or indeed any polynomial, is a special case of this observation.

Comment: If you define $f$ on $\mathbb C\setminus\{10\}$ then it is a removable singularity - that is, a single point, not in the domain of $f,$ at which you can extend the definition and keep the function holomorphic. But it is not a removable singularity if you’ve already defined $f$ there.

Comment: A singularity, for the purpose of this definition, is a point $z_0$ where $f$ is not defined, but with some neighborhood of $z_0,$ except for $z_0,$ is in the domain of $f.$